# MACD signal generator R

Tags: r, loops, quantmod

Simple loop question. Trying to find a loop (not preferred) or anything else to come up with a signal for stoch. if Diff <1, >-1, 1, else 0.

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("SPY", src="yahoo", from="2013-01-01", to="2015-05-01")

y <- na.omit(merge(SPY, SMI(Cl(SPY))))

y$diff <- y$SMI - y$signal

# if Diff <1, >-1, then 1, else 0.
```

Comment: are you just looking for `ifelse(abs(y$diff)>1,1,0)`?

Comment: Yes, but I get the "error in abs(y$diff) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function." Also I'm trying to create the ifelse condition when it below 1 and above -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question regarding your comment to @MrFlick is that you want to map the Difference (y$diff) for values below -1 to -1, values above 1 to 1 and the remaining  values to 0 this line will do it:

```
y$diff.map <- ifelse(y$diff>1,1,ifelse(y$diff< -1,-1,0))
```

In reply to your updated comment the line below will map values between -1 and +1 to 1 and values outside this range to zero.

```
y$diff.map <- ifelse(y$diff >= -1 & y$diff <= 1,1,0)
```

Comment: This is basically what I want. However, I just need the diff.map signal to equal 1 whe diff values are between -1 and 1.